# Send a POST request via Axios to a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, rest, firebase, google-cloud-functions, axios

I try to send a simple request to a Firebase function, but I get the same error every time... Apparently, the Firebase function does not receive the data I want to transmit from the Axios request.

This is the Firebase function :

```
[...] // Some imports

exports.completeProfile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  // Debug
  console.log(req); 
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.method);
  console.log("Test: " + userId + ", " + profilePicture + ", " + username);

  // We recover the data
  const userId = req.body.userId; // return "undefined"
  const profilePicture = req.body.profilePicture; // return "undefined"
  const username = req.body.username; // return "undefined"

  // we're checking to see if they've been transferred
  if (!userId || !profilePicture || !username) {
    // At least one of the 3 required data is not completed
    console.error("Error level 1: missing data");
    return res.status(400).send("Error: missing data");
  }

  [...] // (We have all the data, we continue the function)

});
```

And here is my Axios request :

```
axios
    .post(
        '<FIREBASE CLOUD FUNCTION URL>',
        {
            userId: '12345667',
            profilePicture: 'https://profilepicture.com/url',
            username: 'test',
        }
    )
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

When I run the Axios query, I always come across the "Network Error" error. Here is what **console.log(error);** gives :
[image]

And here are the server logs:
[image]

How to solve the problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried repicating the same request using Postman, and seeing what result you are getting?

Comment: @gillyhl Very good idea. The request always gives the same error. (https://i.imgur.com/keQElQC.png)

Comment: @gillyhl So it would come from the Firebase function, right?

Comment: Yes, that would be the firebase function, try putting the test console log after recovering the data and see what comes out

Comment: Actually it looks like it is trying to do an OPTIONS call as well as a POST. This will be an CORS issue

Comment: @gillyhl The console returns the same logs as in the post.

Comment: Try adding this as a header: ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *```

Comment: @gillyhl It still doesn't work... (https://i.imgur.com/OMahrkC.png). And it's the same thing when I make a GET request.

Comment: What are the server logs saying when you make these postman requests?

Comment: @gillyhl Where can we see that?

Comment: The logs that look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNcvr.png

Comment: @gillyhl Here it is : https://i.imgur.com/pxZMFmw.png

Comment: Try this ```const body = JSON.parse(req.body.toString())``` and then access userId, etc. by going ```body.userId```

Comment: @gillyhl I get "Error: could not handle the request" on PostMan and this on the logs : https://i.imgur.com/9wovHZk.png

Comment: The modified code : https://i.imgur.com/vo3WAKT.png

Comment: Can you expand the IncomingMessage part of the server log, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168230/discussion-between-jean-and-gillyhl).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change your firebase code to this

```
var cors = require("cors");
completeProfileFn = (req, res) => {
  // Debug
  console.log(req);
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.method);
  console.log("Test: " + userId + ", " + profilePicture + ", " + username);

  // We recover the data
  const userId = req.body.userId; // return "undefined"
  const profilePicture = req.body.profilePicture; // return "undefined"
  const username = req.body.username; // return "undefined"

  // we're checking to see if they've been transferred
  if (!userId || !profilePicture || !username) {
    // At least one of the 3 required data is not completed
    console.error("Error level 1: missing data");
    return res.status(400).send("Error: missing data");
  }

  // (We have all the data, we continue the function)
};

// CORS and Cloud Functions export logic
exports.completeProfile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var corsFn = cors();
  corsFn(req, res, function() {
    completeProfileFn(req, res);
  });
});
```

It is a CORS issue.

Comment: Finaly a solution that worked, was about to rewrite the entire logic with express, but your answer came to the rescue, thanks :D