# Consuming external api with Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to consume an external api with Firebase Functions, but it gives a time out error when I use OPTIONS, when I use GET to work normally.
I don't want to use **const request = require('request');** or **var rp = require('request-promise');**, as they are obsolete.
What may be wrong, I await help from colleagues.

````
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
// Permitir solicitações de origem cruzada automaticamente
app.use(cors({
    origin: true
}));
//app.use(cors());


app.get('/criarcliente', (req, res) => {

    let uri = "https://api.iugu.com/v1/customers?api_token=<mytoken>";
    let headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    let body = {
        custom_variables: [{
            name: 'fantasia',
            value: 'Dolci Technology'
        }, {
            name: 'vendedor',
        value: ''
        }],
        email: 'teste1@teste1.com',
        name: 'John Dolci',
        phone: 9999999,
        phone_prefix: 66,
        cpf_cnpj: '00000000000',
        cc_emails: 'test@test.com',
        zip_code: '78520000',
        number: '49',
        street: 'Name Street',
        city: 'Guarantã do Norte',
        state: 'MT',
        district: 'Jardim Araguaia'
    }

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: uri,
        body: body,
        headers: headers,
        json: true
    };

    const https = require('https');

    var req = https.request(options, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            res.send(result);
        });
        console.log("aqui");
    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });


}); ```
````

Answer (score 1):

There are two points that I would point out to your case. First, you need to confirm that you are using the Blaze plan in your billing. As clarified in the official [pricing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), in case you are not and are trying to use a non Google-owned service, you won't be able to do it and this will cause an error.

The second point would be to use the [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) library within your application. It's the one that I believe to be most used with Node.js to allow you access to third-party application within Cloud Functions - I would say that it's pretty easy to use as well. You should find a whole example on using it with third-party API [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952295/how-to-do-axios-request-from-firebase-cloud-function).

To summarize, take a look at your pricing, as it's the most common issue to be caused and give it a try with `axios`, to confirm that you can avoid the error with it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it has already helped me a lot, me using the Blaze plan. With GET I can normally, I only have problems with PUT and POST, this example that you told me you are using GET, by any chance you don't have an example using POST or PUT?

Comment: Hi @LucasDolci you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806920/12767257) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650057/send-a-post-request-via-axios-to-a-firebase-cloud-function) for examples using `POST`. Please, if you think my answer helped you, consider accepting it, so the Community can have a confirmation that this case was solved/helped properly. :)